# Loging / Benchmarking compression with 7Zip

Tags: compression, benchmarking, 7zip

I want to compress different files with different sizes in 7Zip application to use its different compression methods

How can I benchmark/log the time, ratio, memory usage and other elements? does 7zip has any tool or any command to keep track of it. or after compression finished give a summary of these elements?

Comment: What have you thought of yourself ? What have you tried ? :)

Comment: @MortenJensen what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean what have you tried so far, that didn't work? I think it's widely expected of you to have put some effort into the issue yourself, before posting your question to SO. What did you try so far that did not work ?

Answer (score 0):

I created this Github repository with some Batchfiles which I use myself for benchmarking: [7-Zip-Benchmarking](https://github.com/mcmilk/7-Zip-Benchmarking) it is using the [wtime](https://github.com/mcmilk/wtime) tool for that.

Here is an example o the usage:

```
Command: wtime 7z a silesia.7z -mmt=off -mx15 silesia

TIMES in milliseconds
RunningTime................. 32104
UserTime.................... 31793
KernelTime.................. 249

MEMORY in KiB
PageFaultCount.............. 112
PeakWorkingSetSize.......... 34856
WorkingSetSize.............. 20
QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage..... 85
QuotaPagedPoolUsage......... 0
QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage.. 6
QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage...... 0
PagefileUsage............... 0
PeakPagefileUsage........... 36296

IO count
ReadOperationCount.......... 81
WriteOperationCount......... 34
OtherOperationCount......... 115
ReadTransferCount........... 211939037
WriteTransferCount.......... 58043652
OtherTransferCount.......... 3414
```

Now the same, but with 4 threads:

```
Command: wtime 7z a silesia.7z -mmt=4 -mx15 silesia

TIMES in milliseconds
RunningTime................. 11668
UserTime.................... 43025
KernelTime.................. 202

MEMORY in KiB
PageFaultCount.............. 124
PeakWorkingSetSize.......... 133688
WorkingSetSize.............. 20
QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage..... 85
QuotaPagedPoolUsage......... 0
QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage.. 7
QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage...... 0
PagefileUsage............... 0
PeakPagefileUsage........... 184848

IO count
ReadOperationCount.......... 81
WriteOperationCount......... 34
OtherOperationCount......... 115
ReadTransferCount........... 211939037
WriteTransferCount.......... 58043652
OtherTransferCount.......... 3414
```

Change the command line, to fit your needs with different files, filetypes and so on ...

Comment: If you think that OP question was regarding code, can you please put some example of the code needed to reply his question?